# Why is this attempt at writing functional code with lodash-fp not behaving as I expect?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

#### Background

It's my understanding that by currying a function, you instruct it to return a function if it's arity is not met and this mechanism is key to understanding functional composition. I've found many tutorials online, but not many that demonstrate this using `lodash-fp` and user-defined-functions. It appears that I'm missing a concept in the below code snippet, because my composed function throws an error when I invoke it with no arguments.

#### Problem

I expect the final function call below to return a function, waiting for the data to be passed in, but instead it attempts to flow through each function. These two functions can be called independently and they return functions instead of attempting to execute the logic with no arguments. What am I missing that causes a runtime error when trying to execute the combined function with no arguments?

#### Complete Code

```
const compose = require('lodash/fp/compose');
const curry = require('lodash/fp/curry');

const toUpper = curry(input => {
    return input.toUpperCase()
})

//This returns a function, which is correct because it's a curried function and it's arity has not been satisfied
console.log(toUpper())

//This returns what I expect, which is "HELLO WORLD"
console.log(toUpper("hello world"))

const reverseString = curry(input => {
    return input.split("").reverse().join("")
})

//"olleh" looks right to me!
console.log(reverseString("hello"))

//Let's try putting it all together with function composition
const uppercaseAndReverse = compose(reverseString, toUpper)

//"OLLEH" is exactly what I expected
console.log(uppercaseAndReverse("hello"))

//ERROR: input.split is not a function
console.log(uppercaseAndReverse())
```

[The RunKit version of this code is here](https://runkit.com/seanlindo/lodash-fp-w-user-defined-functions-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the function being curried, `reverseString`, is composed with another function, `lodash#toUpper`. Since an invocation of a composed function using `lodash#compose` is evaluated from last to first. A call from `uppercaseAndReverse()` invokes `lodash#toUpper()` first which returns `undefined`, and passes it to `reverseString` that treats it as a parameter.

If you wish for the `uppercaseAndReverse` composition to curry then use `lodash#curryN` instead wherein the first parameter is the arity and the second parameter is the function to curry:

```
const uppercaseAndReverse = curryN(1, compose(reverseString, toUpper))
```

```js
const { compose, curry, curryN } = _;

const toUpper = curry(input => {
    return input.toUpperCase()
})

//This returns a function, which is correct because it's a curried function and it's arity has not been satisfied
console.log(toUpper())

//This returns what I expect, which is "HELLO WORLD"
console.log(toUpper("hello world"))

const reverseString = curry(input => {
    return input.split("").reverse().join("")
})

//"olleh" looks right to me!
console.log(reverseString("hello"))

//Let's try putting it all together with function composition
const uppercaseAndReverse = curryN(1, compose(reverseString, toUpper))

//"OLLEH" is exactly what I expected
console.log(uppercaseAndReverse("hello"))

//ERROR: input.split is not a function
console.log(uppercaseAndReverse())
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Note that a composed function does not contain any arity, hence, simply using `lodash#curry` wouldn't work.

Comment: curryN was the answer! Conceptually, I don't understand why it makes sense to flow `undefined` to the next function in the composition chain.